# getchar() in c program - Eclipse Luna - Permission Denied

Tags: c, windows, mingw32, getchar, eclipse-luna

**Integer and Float** based programs are working good in my **Eclipse Luna** Installation, without any **permission** *problems created by Windows Process*, but a **string** based C Program, gives *errors or sometimes builds but empty console*.

I hold a latest copy of

`Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers`

`Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) - Build id: 20140925-1800`

and

`MinGW - mingw version 0.6.2`

on a `Window 7 Ultimate 32-bit` operating system.

This would be my code

[image: Code]

This screenshot would be after the first build `Ctrl+B`

[image: First Build]

First Build shows no error/exceptions.

But when I tried to run it,

[image: Run]

I get empty console, I believe atleast **Enter String** should have been present if error starts from `getchar`, but surprisingly the console is *empty*

I tried rebuilding it, below message came up.

[image: Rebuild Code]

I tried running it again `Ctrl + F11`

[image: Run Code]

It's again empty.

I am not able to replicate the **Permission Denied** scenario, but however on monitoring the process I found this

[image: Process]

but as soon as I end these processes,  It was capable of building, but empty console again with no messages in problems tab. On occasions, these *permission denied* is appearing, and as soon as I end the process, this disappears.

Comment: Where does this "permission denied" message come from. What *exactly* did you do just before the message appeared? Please update your question with this information, and with a copy-and-pasted copy of the entire error message.

Comment: Since `stdout` is typically (at least) line buffered or fully buffered, and your `printf()` call does not include a newline, it is not guaranteed that your prompt string will be output when you seem to think it should be...